# calling smart contract function that has parameters using web3.js

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js

Here is the problem I am having with web3.js 0.19.0:

```
//this is just a smart contract i just picked up from etherscan
var c = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"tokenBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"users","type":"address[]"},{"name":"tokens","type":"address[]"}],"name":"balances","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"}]);
var contract = c.at("0xb1F8e55c7f64D203C1400B9D8555d050F94aDF39");

//This is not working
contract.methods.tokenBalance("0x", "0x").call((err, balance) => {
        console.log({err, balance});
})
```

It says that contract.methods is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're using a mix of web3.js 1.0 syntax and web3.js 0.2.x syntax. Which library are you using? Be sure to read the documentation for that version.

Comment: i am using 0.19.0 @smarx